# delete object from an array Iphone

Tags: iphone, arrays, object, sdk

I have 2 NSMutableArraL in a tableview class.
One array holds a list, and the second array holds sub list.

When i delete object from the list array, i want to delete from the subList array the object in the same indexPath as the list array.

The NSLog provides the correct count of objects in both arrays before and after deleting the objects, but when i load the view of the subList array on the table, it looks like all the cells of the subList array are empty.

One more important info is that each subList object is array.

Here is the function for deleting the cells:

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
[list removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"delete list: %d",[list count]);

[subList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"delete subList: %d",[subList count]);

[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

[self saveData];
```

}

I hope my question is clear.
Thanks
EKT

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling [UITableView reloadData] after you change the arrays? The table view might not be getting refreshed properly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The list array is presented on the table correctly after deleting the object, and the subList is only saved to a file after deleting. when the user select a row in the list tableview, it push a new UITableView class that get the subList array from the saved file and load a new tableview.

Comment: sorry I clicked the accepted answer by mistake.. still have the same issue

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem with the deletion, and not a problem with writing/reading from the file?

Comment: yes because the user can add objects to the array and i can navigate between the tableview and see all the correct data presented. only when i delete (or move rows) in the list TableView, all the cells looks empty. The NSLOG after deleting and shows the correct amount of cells in both arrays. I will try to explain a little more: Each time I select the row in the list TableView, the subList class present the array object that sits in the subList array according to the selected indexPath in the list TableView. it all show the correct data until I delete object from the subList array

Comment: I tried something that got me confused... the issue is not when I delete object from the subList array. I delete object from the list array and the whole data from the subList object is deleted. any idea for that?

Comment: Thank you I found the problem. when you press the back bar button it does not remember the new data unless you restart the application. I solved it by init the array again from the saved file inside the delete row function